Azure Functions App view in Azure portal cannot fetch the functions list
The functions app is deployed to the Functions App in a Linux app service plan in a docker container. The functions are running fine, but on the Functions App view, the portal is unable to fetch the list of functions deployed to the app.
The functions app runs in in-process mode, on dotnet 6.
Unfortunately, the only information about the failing fetch is "Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.".
The fact that the functions are all running just fine, seems to indicate there's nothing wrong in the deploy as such. There are no network restrictions applied to the app service, there are no private endpoints defined. The functions are all service bus triggers and timer triggers.
If anyone has a useful tip, more than welcome, as this situation is no deal breaker, but it is irritating nonetheless :-).
Relevant app settings:
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
    "value": "~4",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "dotnet",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTOVERVNET",
    "value": "0",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_OVERRIDE_STICKY_EXTENSION_VERSIONS",
    "value": "1",
    "slotSetting": false
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE",
    "value": "false",
    "slotSetting": false
  }


Please share the function code if possible.

Company code, I'm not allowed to share the code

Share the application settings of your function app

@PravallikaKV I updated the post with the relevant app settings.

Do you have the setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 in function app?

No I didn't. Turned it on now, and redeployed, but same issue.


By default, persistent storage is disabled on Linux custom containers as mentioned in MSDOC.

Set the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE app setting value to true to enable Persistent storage in function app.

Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime

This error my occur if the application setting AzureWebJobsStorage is missing or invalid in the function app.

Add the application setting "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storage_connection_string" in Function App=>Settings=>Environment variables.



Add the setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1 in the function app before deploying the function to Azure.

If you have enabled the managed identity or network restrictions, enable public access and disable the managed identity and redeploy the function.
Configure the Diagnostic settings to send the function app logs to log Analytics workspace in the function app to analyze the reason of 500 errors.

Check the Application logs and function app logs using the query FunctionAppLogs to get the detailed errors.


Thanks! Will test this out one of the following days
